# Is it safe to give a rabies booster 2 weeks after inital vaccine?

Tags: dogs, vaccination

I have a mixed breed dog that has not been given an annual antirabies vaccine. Suddenly at the age of 5 years, my dog killed a rat so I decided to give him an antirabies vaccine. Then my vet advised that after his 1st shot, another antirabies shot should be given after 2 weeks. Is it safe? I'm scared of the possible overdose of the vaccine.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the vaccine company when rabies should be boostered, typically it ranges from every 1 to 3 years.

The protocol for the vaccine that your vet has may be to booster in 2 weeks time. The only way to know for sure is to contact the vaccine company and enquire more about the protocol. You can get the company information from your veterinarian.

Answer (score 0):

It is common for dogs without a vaccination history OR without proof of what vaccines have been given to get the puppy rabies, as well as it's second (usually given a year later) as a booster shot. This is not harmful to your dog, and rescue dogs who MAY HAVE already received a vaccination are given the vaccine twice all the time either accidentally or so there can be legal/paper proof the vaccine was given. This is not dangerous. It's common to receive 2 in one month or over the course of 2-3 months. 2 weeks in-between may be a little close together, but will not harm your dog unless an allergy to the vaccine and/or ingredients in it, is present.

Answer (score -1):

You see the first shot your dog is going to have is the shot he/she should have had when it was a puppy so it won't harm your dog if it gets another vaccine in two weeks. Your dog's body is much stronger now than a puppy's. Usually it takes a month to get to the next vaccine, but half a month is good for a dog to get a puppy's vaccine.